# How exactly do I explain why the proof is incorrect?

Tags: induction

Explain in detail why the following “proof” is incorrect.

**Theorem $1$.** *All positive integers are equal.*

*Proof.* We show that any two positive integers are equal, from which the result follows. We do this by induction on the maximum of the two numbers. Let $P (n)$ be the statement “if $r$ and $s$ are positive integers and max{$r, s$} = $n$ then $r = s$”.

Clearly $P (1)$ is true. Suppose that $P (n)$ is true and let $r, s$ be positive integers whose maximum is $n + 1$. Then max{$r−1,s−1$} = $n$. By the inductive hypothesis, $r−1=s−1$ and hence $r=s$. Thus $P(n+1)$is true.

The result is now proved by mathematical induction.

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't quite seem to be the horses question.

Comment: $(r-1, s-1)$ may not be positive integers.  One or the other may equal 0.